# Converse order relations flip completeness property

Tags: order-theory, supremum-and-infimum

To me it seems trivially true that if $A$ is a set ordered by relation $C$ denoted $<_C$ and $A$ has the greatest lower bound property (or least upper bound property), then $A$ ordered by the converse relation $D$ defined as $(b,a)\in D$ if $(a,b)\in C$ and denoted $<_D$ has the least upper bound property (or greatest lower bound property).

This isn't an individual problem I'm trying to solve, just part of an argument I'm trying to give to a [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2283678/689775) (g.l.b. property $\implies$ l.u.b. property) in Munkres' Topology.

A proof would go something like showing how under $<_C$, given a subset $A_0\subset A$ bounded below, $A_0$ is bounded above under $<_D$. Then $\inf A_0$ under $<_C$ is such that $\inf A_0\leq_C x$ for all $x\in A\iff\inf A_0\ge_D x$ for all $x\in A_0$. And so on, eventually showing $\inf A_0$ under $<_C$ equals $\sup A_0$ under $<_D$.

Is this right?

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify what is g.l.b. property. It is a fact that if the poset $(P,\leq)$ is such that for all $A\subseteq P$, there is $a\in P$ such that $a=\bigwedge A$ ($a$ is the greatest lower bound of $A$), then the poset also has the property that for all $A\subseteq P$, there is $b\in P$ such that $b=\bigvee A$ ($b$ is the least upper bound of $A$). It's only a matter of applying the original property to the set of upper bounds of $A$. This makes $(P,\leq)$ a complete lattice. Now, it may happen that that property is only for $\varnothing\neq A\subseteq P$. It's very different...

Comment: @amrsa the greatest lower bound property indeed is only for non empty subsets bounded below. My question really is if you have the g.l.b. property for some set with some order, don’t you have the least upper bound property for that same set under the converse order relation?

Comment: Yes, since the posets are [dual of each other](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(order_theory)#Examples).

Comment: @amrsa thank you very much, this is all I needed. That's exactly the notion I was looking for.